# How to insert a list/array of values into NumPy array matrix at specified list of row/column index locations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Lets say I have the following NumPy array matrix:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((4,4))
A
Out[7]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Next, say I have the following index lists:

```
row_indexes = [0,2,3]
column_indexes = [0,2,1]
```

and a list of corresponding values:

```
values = [10, 20, 30]
```

**My question is:** How can I insert the list of `values` into the matrix `A` as efficiently as possible (computation time is relevant) at the row/column index locations specified by `row_indexes` and `column_indexes` so that after this operation, `A` would equal:

```
array([[10.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 20.,  0.],
       [ 0., 30.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: `A[row_indexes, column_indexes] = values`?, `numba` could be faster if you omit bound checks.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thank you for your help! For some reason I got an error earlier due to dimension mismatch when I tried this. I check again why this went wrong.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny It indeed did work, I had other problem in my code that caused the mismatch. So this answers my question. Thank you!